# Bluetooth crashing when using updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals on OS X

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have written an iOS app where the iOS device is both a BTLE central and peripheral and multiple devices can exchange data. I tried to bring the peripheral part of the app to OS X. The problem is that as soon as I try to transfer data from an OS X peripheral to an iOS central via `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals`, BTLE on OS X crashes pretty much completely.

This means:

1) the OS X computer is not picked up by any iOS device anymore

2) peripheral manager doesn't do anything anymore - no callbacks are called, nothing

3) When I restart the app on OS X, peripheral manager does never change its state to PoweredOn or any other state

4) The only way to get BTLE working on OS X again after that is rebooting or using `sudo killall blued`

The exact same code works fine on iOS, I have no idea what's going on. Basically, I am doing this:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    dispatch_queue_t peripheralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("connichiwaperipheralqueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:peripheralQueue];
    return self;
}

- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheralManager {
    if (peripheralManager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        [self.peripheralManager addService:self.advertisedService];
        [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_UUID]] }];
    }
}

- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral central:(CBCentral *)central didSubscribeToCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic {
    if (characteristic == self.advertisedInitialCharacteristic) {
        [self _sendInitialToCentral:central];
    }
}

- (void)_sendInitialToCentral:(CBCentral *)central {   
    NSDictionary *sendDictionary = @{ /* some dictionary, but i've also tried with a short, simple string */ };
    NSData *initialData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sendDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    BOOL didSend = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:initialData forCharacteristic:self.advertisedInitialCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:@[central]];
}
```

, whereas `self.advertisedService` is a service that contains `self.advertisedInitialCharacteristic` and `BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_UUID` is a UUID that the iOS device is looking for.

When this is executed, the iOS device picks up the OS X machine, discovers the service, discovers the characteristic and then the OS X machine executes `_sendInitialToCentral:`. Here, `didSend` becomes `true` but after that BTLE basically stops doing anything on the machine and the new value never arrives at the iOS device.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong? I can't see the issue here. Running OS X 10.9.3

### Update

Just wanted to add that I just tested this with another machine and the same thing was happening.

### Update 2

**Found the reason**: The cause of this problem is that I am handing a CBCentral to `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals:`. If I change the last parameter to `nil` the data is sent. The problem is that I NEED to send the data to a specific central, I do NOT want to broadcast them. Anybody has any idea what is going on here and how to fix this?

Comment: What is in your send dictionary? I note that you say you have tried a short string, but how short?  BLE is limited to 20 bytes per transfer

Comment: That's actually why I tried it - on iOS, it seems possible to send more than 20 bytes (not sure why, but it works). But even if I try a one-character string (or an empty string, for that matter) the same thing happens on OS X. And the strange thing is that `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals` returns `true`, so I guess it shouldn't be a problem with the data?

Comment: Yes, it seems that `maximumUpdateValueLength` property on the CBCentral indicates how many bytes can be written, with data after this truncated. Do you get anything in the OSX logs from blued?

Comment: Good thinking. When starting the app I get `blued[59087]: ****** properties = 0x10, permissions = 0x1, write? 0, w/o res? 0`, which seems to represent the advertised characteristic. Nothing is logged when the data is sent, though. After a while, I get another message, but I'm not 100% sure if it is related: `kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0x6000 ****`

Comment: found the problem, see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer this: It seems this was a bug in Mavericks. This issue (and a lot others with BTLE) were completely solved in Yosemite.

On Mavericks, only passing `nil` to the last parameter of `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals` seems to make BTLE work.